# MySQL sub-query AND 'NOT IN'

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

sorry if this has been answered before; I'm a little unsure how best to describe this problem never mind search for it. But here goes...

Basically I have a 'projects' table, which holds and 'id' and a 'title'. I also have a 'projects_history' table which holds information when (IF) the project is set to archived (a boolean value). It has a 'pid' key that references the project - there can be more than one record for each project as it is updated (in order to track who sets the value to what).

There's also a 'project_enquiries' table that holds information on enquiries that have been raised for the project, so there is a 'pid' key that references 'projects'. Similarly, there's a 'project_enquiry_history' table that records when (IF) the enquiry is set to closed (a boolean value). It has a 'eid' key that references the project_enquiry - there can be more than one record for each enquiry as it is updated (in order to track who sets the value to what).

My query aims to pull out the projects that haven't been archived (so either there is no record in 'project_history' or the most recent record for the project has 'archived' = 0), which have enquiries that are still open (so either there is no record in 'project_enquiry_history' or the most recent record for the enquiry has 'open' = 1).

I'm really struggling on where to start with the query.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that if there is no record in `project_history`, then you will need to do a `left join` of your `projects` table on the `project_history` table using your project id to discover this. You will have entries in the results that are null in the columns for `project_history` where there is no corresponding entry. You can then chain that process, using the result to do another left join on the 'project_enquiry_history' to find the items that have no entries.

You can also use these results as normal, to do selects of the data.

It will look something like:

`SELECT * from project p LEFT OUTER JOIN project_history ph ON P.ID=ph.pid
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN project_enquiry_history peh ON peh.ID=ph.pid
WHERE (archived is NULL OR archived=0)
      AND (open is NULL OR open=1)`

You may have to tweak this to find the most recent if you are using timestamps and such.

Comment: Thanks Poodlehat. That's helped a lot, but I'm not sure how to find the most recent? I'm using a unix timestamp stored as an INT to record the date, under the field 'created'.

Comment: You can probably do a MAX on it then - the 32-bit UNIX timestamp won't roll over until 2038, if that isn't a concern for your application. Instead of doing `LEFT OUTER JOIN project_history ph` above, do something like `LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ph.pid, MAX(ph.created) FROM project_history ph, project p WHERE P.ID=ph.pid GROUP BY pid) x ON p.id=x.pid`

Comment: Sorry for not replying any earlier. I've just tried what you have suggested but now I am getting an error that the archived column doesn't exist. My query as it stands is now 

`SELECT DISTINCT p.id
FROM projects p
L1EFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ph.pid, MAX(ph.created) FROM project_history ph, projects p WHERE P.ID=ph.pid GROUP BY pid) x ON p.id=x.pid
LEFT OUTER JOIN project_enquiries pe ON P.ID = pe.pid
LEFT OUTER JOIN project_enquiry_history peh ON peh.eid = pe.id
WHERE (
archived IS NULL
OR archived =0
)
AND (

OPEN IS NULL
OR OPEN =1
)`

Comment: Ok this is what I have so far `SELECT DISTINCT p.id
FROM projects p
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ph.pid, ph.archived, MAX(ph.created) FROM project_history ph, projects p WHERE P.ID=ph.pid GROUP BY pid) x ON p.id=x.pid
LEFT OUTER JOIN project_enquiries pe ON P.ID = pe.pid
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT peh.eid, peh.open, MAX(peh.created) FROM project_enquiry_history peh, project_enquiries pe WHERE pe.ID=peh.eid GROUP BY pid) y ON pe.id=y.eid
WHERE (
archived IS NULL
OR archived =0
)
AND (

OPEN IS NULL
OR OPEN =1
)` however it doesn't seem to pick out the latest project_enquiry_history record